# How to filter Error from Power Query list

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a list and would like to remove any that are Errors. In this particular case I have a list of tables but would prefer a generic answer.

I am currently using

```
RemovedErrors = List.Select(
    List.Transform(List.Positions(MyList), each try MyList{_} otherwise null),
    each _ <> null
)
```

but this is quite ugly, and also filters out nulls (which I might want to keep).

Answer (score 2):

If, instead of using "Nulls" as my Try Otherwise default, I use something like "BadError"...like this:

[image]

Then I can use `List.RemoveItems(#"Added Custom"[Custom],{"BadError"})` to remove the "BadError" entries from the list...like this:

[image]

That should leave your nulls alone.

Comment: This seems better than using null, but still leaves the issue of what to do if you can't identify an invalid value to use as the default. e.g. if you have a list of mixed types, it's difficult to choose a default value that couldn't also be a valid non-error value.

Comment: You might want to check out [this site](http://blog.gbrueckl.at/2013/12/error-handling-in-power-query/). Especially the section, _Error-handling on cell-level with error details_. You might be able to use `HasError` to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Home tab you can click on Remove Rows > Remove Errors.

[image: Remove Errors]

As you can see in the formula bar, the M code for this action looks like

```
= Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(TableName, {"ColumnWithErrors"})
```

---

**Edit:** This does not work with a list. However, you can convert a list to a table using `Table.FromColumns({List})` and then apply the above. You can Convert to List (under the Transform tab) if you want to switch back to a list after removing errors.

Some other possibilities are given on [this community.powerbi.com thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Removing-errors-from-list-not-column-in-Power-Query-M/m-p/78765).

Comment: But I don't think Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors works on a list?

Comment: @JamesElderfield You are correct. Please see my edit.